# setting up gravitars for my posts through users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just set it up so that when a user signs up for my blog it gives them a gravatar in the users index. That works fine but I was thinking of making it so that when that user makes a post it will display their gravatar from the user. I just made a user_id colum to posts through a migration.

here is a copy of my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131114141804) do

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "auth_token"
    t.string   "password_reset_token"
    t.datetime "password_reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "avatar_url"
  end
end
```

models:

user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  has_many :posts

  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar_url(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email).downcase
    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=200"
  end
end
```

was trying to do something new, could anyone help me out and or point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a good look at using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for the attachment process rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.  Paperclip's documentation actually uses a user avatar as an example, so it'd be perfect for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a Rails plugin to integrate with Gravatar rather than doing it yourself:

- [gravtastic](https://github.com/chrislloyd/gravtastic)
- [Gravatar Rails plugin](http://gravatarplugin.rubyforge.org/)